# PHP json_encode string to big float

Tags: php, json, floating-point

Since there is a limit in PHP's float size (max. 14 digit), I use string to work with big float numbers, In my case I've 19 real digits and 2 digits of precision, I need a solution to JSON encode an array which contains these numbers but also type cast them from string to float.

using `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` flag wont help because the numbers are too big

```
<?php
$array = array(
"big_float1" => "9876543210999999999.01",
"big_float2" => "9876543210999999999.01",
"float1" => 2.2
);

$json = json_encode($array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

In above code I need to have JSON object like this
`{"big_float1" : 9876543210999999999.01, "big_float2" : 9876543210999999999.01, "float1" : 2.2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the conversion from string to float needs to be done by PHP this won't be possible. Max integer value for 64-bit PHP is 9223372036854775807 and this is less than what you need. There are couple of workarounds you could try to do:

- send the value as string and decode and cast to float on the receiving end if that system can deal with such big numbers
- break the number into 3 elements: (1) send decimal part as integer in another field; (2) divide the integer part into 2 parts by splitting the string at predetermined position. if you decide to do it for 5th position then you will get `99999` and `98765432109999`. at the receiving end you can recreate the original number by doing `first_part * 10^5 + second_part`
- you can extend your space for integers if you can move out decimal part (and send it in another field) and only deal with positive value of the integer part. In that case when your code calculates the value you can start with `PHP_INT_MIN + value1 + value2 + value4...`. This way you will can use entire 2^64 space (values less than 2^63 will be negative). The only thing is to add 2^64 and the decimal part at the receiving end.
- if you cannot change the way the receiving end decodes the message your only way is to use a subsystem in the target language that can handle such large numbers and use it to send the message. Your processing will be done by PHP and saved to disk, send to a port or make a system call where the small script will handle the processing of the generated message and send it.